# How to calculate the right distance between leaf in a Phylogram

Tags: excel, plot

I'm working on a card sorting project, I'd like to represent with a Phylogram to illustrate properly the distance between leafs and nodes.

I collected all the information about my groups and card in an excel spreadsheet, I can find similarities and all the rest of things, but I don't have a clue on how to find a "formula" to generate the distance to be used in the following example.

http://bl.ocks.org/kueda/raw/1036776/3d0e556d5c891a6b3851a38377457d86440bfd00/

Any idea if this can be done programmatically or I should assign arbitrary values?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Not sure exactly what you mean by "distance"...

Comment: Sounds interesting but utterly obscure. You have data in an Excel spreadsheet but have provided no information about what that data is and how it is organized. Based on the data you want to compute some numbers but have provided no clue as to what these numbers are or how they relate to the data. And -- it has something or other to do with an interesting picture. I'm sure that there is a VBA solution to your problem but I am utterly clueless about what that solution is since I am utterly clueless about what your actual problem is.

Comment: Well, the point is I have the "data" as in the leafs name, but not a numeric value to show. If you look at the example above, and the json file used by D3 to plot the graph you can see the "distance" value that in some way has been calculated. Now, with the dataset I have, I can come up with a Json file that is similar, but does not have any distance which I don't know at all how to calculate.

Comment: @AndreaMoro Well -- what does the distance *mean*? Understanding the meaning of a number is a good first step towards understanding how to compute it.

Comment: Well, I'd say it's a difficult concept to explain in a comment. Let me try, though I'm trying to understand it myself. Say you have two nodes and two leafs, one each node. A total of 5 people voted for the preference on how distribute the leaf with the results mentioned, but 3 said node A is more likely than B. The distance should show the main root to node A shorter than to node B. Does it make sense?